# autoCompleteTextView error Unresolved reference: setSimpleItems when building

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

when I tried to assign a list to autoCompleteTextView according to the documentation, android studio started to highlight in red and does not allow me to build the project, what could be the problem?

[screenshot from AS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scEZe.png)

I did not find anything on the Internet, absolutely, searched everything and in general no one had this problem